# How can I keep output shown in the IPython notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a Jupyter notebook that runs correctly. I want to keep the output cell inside of the notebook to see output without running again. I noticed that when I run the notebook cell by cell, it doesn’t show out[] after each In[] cell.

How can I have an save my notebook in a way that all outputs show without re-running?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get Out[], be sure to write a single variable at the bottom of the cell. The "Out[*]" variable equals to it.

Following is an example, Out[1] is the variable "v"

[image: sample 1]

It's the same for figure, you can write code like this
[image: figure code sample]

do not write expression only, it won't output anything

Comment: I mistook "print" before, it won't save variable in "Out".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but even for this small example, I don’t have out[] structure when I run the cell.

[image: simple example output in notebook]

In my case, I want to show my output for diagrams inside of the notebook.
I used figure.show() or display(figure), I can see the result but every time I open the notebook I should run again to see the figures, otherwise, it's a white cell in output.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Apparently it works for these samples. I attached a screenshot here. I used "plotly.graph_objects" to plot a map. It shows the map correctly, but it's not in the out[*].
[image]